# How to determine session value at Controller

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-8, laravel-session

I have set a session value like this at Blade:

```
@php
if(...){
    Session::put('sent','city')
}else{
    Session::put('sent','country')
}
@endphp
```

And now, I need to check the `sent` session value at the Controller but don't know how...

So if you know, please help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session#retrieving-data - What have you tried and what happens?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session#determining-if-an-item-exists-in-the-session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same as you are doing for inserting the value ([documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session#retrieving-data)):

```
public class SomeController{
  public function some_method(){
    $value = session()->get('sent');
    // or if you are not certain that the value is being set
    $value = session()->get('sent', 'default_value');
  }
}
```